# Before you can run VMware several modules must be compiled (vmmon and vmnet)

Tags: gcc, vmware, pop-os, vmware-workstation

I just restarted my Pop!_OS and when trying to open vmware it says I have to compile several modules. It then goes onto trying to compile vmmon and vmnet, which fails. and gives me an error log file.

I've tried changing gcc version with  `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 100`, this didn't seem to change the error files.

I've also tried running `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` but this also  fails.

Error log file:

```
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 Log for VMware Workstation pid=26414 version=17.0.2 build=build-21581411 option=Release
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 The host is x86_64.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 Host is Linux 6.5.4-76060504-generic Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS Pop!_OS 22.04
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 Host offset from UTC is +02:00.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/grimley/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/grimley/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.525Z In(05) host-26414 PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/grimley/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.606Z Wa(03) host-26414 Logging to /tmp/vmware-grimley/vmware-26414.log
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 Created new pathsHash.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 Setting header path for 6.5.4-76060504-generic to "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.614Z In(05) host-26414 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2023-10-17T08:12:11.619Z In(05) host-26414 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.619Z In(05) host-26414 The header path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2023-10-17T08:12:11.885Z In(05) host-26414 found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/Module.symvers
2023-10-17T08:12:11.885Z In(05) host-26414 Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.904Z In(05) host-26414 Read 28017 symbol versions
2023-10-17T08:12:11.904Z In(05) host-26414 Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.904Z In(05) host-26414 Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.904Z In(05) host-26414 Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.907Z In(05) host-26414 "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.907Z In(05) host-26414 Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.909Z In(05) host-26414 "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.922Z In(05) host-26414 to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2023-10-17T08:12:11.922Z In(05) host-26414 to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 Setting header path for 6.5.4-76060504-generic to "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2023-10-17T08:12:11.934Z In(05) host-26414 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2023-10-17T08:12:11.940Z In(05) host-26414 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:11.940Z In(05) host-26414 The header path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2023-10-17T08:12:12.203Z In(05) host-26414 found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/Module.symvers
2023-10-17T08:12:12.203Z In(05) host-26414 Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.221Z In(05) host-26414 Read 28017 symbol versions
2023-10-17T08:12:12.222Z In(05) host-26414 Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include
2023-10-17T08:12:12.222Z In(05) host-26414 Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include
2023-10-17T08:12:12.222Z In(05) host-26414 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.223Z In(05) host-26414 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2023-10-17T08:12:12.223Z In(05) host-26414 /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.223Z In(05) host-26414 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2023-10-17T08:12:12.228Z In(05) host-26414 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.228Z In(05) host-26414 The header path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2023-10-17T08:12:12.229Z In(05) host-26414 Attempting to use a compiler at location "/usr/bin/gcc-12".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.231Z In(05) host-26414 Got gcc version "12".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.231Z In(05) host-26414 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.232Z In(05) host-26414 Got gcc version "12".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.232Z In(05) host-26414 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 No matching PBM set was found for kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2023-10-17T08:12:12.233Z In(05) host-26414 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2023-10-17T08:12:12.239Z In(05) host-26414 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:12.239Z In(05) host-26414 The header path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2023-10-17T08:12:14.992Z In(05) host-26414 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2023-10-17T08:12:14.992Z In(05) host-26414 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:14.992Z In(05) host-26414 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2023-10-17T08:12:14.992Z In(05) host-26414 /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2023-10-17T08:12:14.992Z In(05) host-26414 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2023-10-17T08:12:15.006Z In(05) host-26414 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.5.4-76060504-generic".
2023-10-17T08:12:15.006Z In(05) host-26414 The header path "/lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.5.4-76060504-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2023-10-17T08:12:15.006Z In(05) host-26414 Using temp dir "/tmp".
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 Stopping VMware services:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    VMware Authentication Daemon[71G done
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    Virtual machine monitor[71G done
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/task.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/Module.symvers
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.5.4-76060504-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/driver.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/hub.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/userif.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/netif.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/bridge.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/procfs.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/smac.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only'
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 [AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 Using kernel build system.
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.c: In function ‘MonLoader_Process’:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.c:794:24: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘false’ for the address of ‘entries’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   794 |    if (header->entries == 0 || header->count == 0) {
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       |                        ^~
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.c:57:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/monLoader.h:239:19: note: ‘entries’ declared here
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   239 |    MonLoaderEntry entries[];
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       |                   ^~~~~~~
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.c:33:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:779: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   779 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:97,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/sched.h:23,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.c:31:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:38:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:779: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   779 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:97,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/sched.h:23,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:58:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:779: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   779 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:97,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/sched.h:23,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:31:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:33,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:32,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:47:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:779: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   779 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:97,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/list_lru.h:12,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/fs.h:13,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414                  from /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       | 
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 ERROR: modpost: "__pte_offset_map" [/tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko] undefined!
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:144: /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmmon-only/Module.symvers] Error 1
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic/Makefile:1992: modpost] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: *** [Makefile:117: vmmon.ko] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 Using kernel build system.
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function ‘VNetBridgeSendLargePacket’:
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1413:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘tcp_gso_segment’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414  1413 |    segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, 0);
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       |           tcp_gso_segment
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1413:9: warning: assignment to ‘struct sk_buff *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414  1413 |    segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, 0);
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414       |         ^
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumAndCopyToUser+0x2d: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.4-76060504-generic/Makefile:2040: /tmp/modconfig-Q8NuOz/vmnet-only] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 make: *** [Makefile:117: vmnet.ko] Error 2
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414 Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
2023-10-17T08:12:23.261Z In(05) host-26414
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn’t the compiler (and you’ll have to undo your `update-alternatives`, the GCC package doesn’t use alternatives), it’s that [your kernel is too new](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/Workstation-17-on-Linux-Kernel-6-5-4-will-not-run/td-p/2991009).

You can try [community-provided patches for your version of Workstation](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tree/workstation-17.0.2):

```
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules -b workstation-17.0.2
```

then copy the result (inside `vmware-host-modules`) over your current module source, wherever that is (look for `statVarsVmmon.c`). Next time you boot, the system should be able to build the module correctly.

The safest approach is to either boot an older kernel, or wait for VMware to update Workstation.

Comment: Thank you! The community-provided patch worked :) Just had to comment out some lines before compiling as shown here: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/VM-Workstation-16-1-gt-16-2-1-on-Ubuntu-21-10-broke-everything/m-p/2884892/highlight/true#M173169